# Create a list from the template with content (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, list-template

I have created a simple list and saved as a template:

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately the template has the same ID as regular CustomList:

[image]

This is by design and - I suspect - cannot be changed (the property is read-only).

Now I would like to create a list from this template using CSOM and the following code:

```
$lci =New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation
  $lci.Description=$Description
$lci.Title=$Title
$lci.Templatetype=$TemplateType
$lci.TemplateFeatureID=$TemplateFeatureID

$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.Add($lci)
$ctx.Load($list)
try
 {

     $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
     Write-Host "List " $Title " has been added. "
 }
 catch [Net.WebException]
 { 
    Write-Host $_.Exception.ToString()
 }
```

The list gets created, but it doesn't have my custom view and the content (items I created). Basically it is not based on my template but the Custom List default template. Based on user21832's answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77582/how-can-one-create-a-custom-list-in-jsom-based-on-a-custom-list-template-stp-i) this is by design.

So how can I create a list based on a template? Can I update somehow the ID? Can I use another function? Can I set the template's ID when creating it? When I use UI, the template is applied without issues. Any idea how does the code do it in the background?